# IRC command-line client for Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, irc

I'm looking for a (preferably free and/or open source) IRC client running on the Windows' command line. I searched for a while and found that this kind of tools exists for Linux and that you can improvise something with telnet, but is there a native IRC client that can be executed within cmd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`irssi`](http://www.irssi.org/documentation) is open source terminal based IRC client for multiple platform including windows. It can be operated by default windows command-line or puttycyg.

Comment: Hm. It seems good, but I can only start it by executing the .bat, and then it opens in a new window. If I try to put it on the PATH and start it by typing "irssi", the terminal just close. Is it normal?

Comment: You need to pass command-line parameters, here is manual explaining parameters required on [1st index](http://irssi.org/documentation/manual).

Comment: @Timst I was able to use the version available at https://github.com/q3aql/irssi-win and launch irssi.exe rather than irssi.bat from the bin folder directly, which avoids the whole new window issue.